# Why is $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{[0,\infty)})$ a product sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}^{[0,\infty)}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I was working on some problem showing an equality between sigma algebras for $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{[0,\infty)})$ and thought at first, that this space, simply because of the $\mathcal{B}$, is in some sense generated by the open sets in the function space $\mathbb{R}^{[0,\infty)}$. So I immeadiately thought you could take open sets around functions like
$$B_{\epsilon}(f)=\{g: g\in (f-\epsilon,f+\epsilon)\}$$
but that would only work somehow if you evaluate it pointwise for some $x\in[0,\infty)$ as $f$ is a function. However, this makes little to no sense.

The definition of the product sigma algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{[0,\infty)})$ (hopefully no mistakes) is given by
$$\sigma(\{\times_{x\in [0,\infty)} B_x: \ B_x \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\forall x\in [0,\infty) \ \text{and} \ B_x \neq [0,\infty) \ \text{only for finitely many}\ x\in [0,\infty)\}).$$

I must have missed it when it was introduced but what is the intuition behind it since I tend to think of $\mathbb{R}^{[0,\infty)}$ being the space of functions from $[0,\infty)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ as "one" space and a function as "one" point and therefore I would like to have "one" sigma algebra on that space? Why is it that we have that the sigma algebra of that one set is a product sigma algebra? If we would have $\mathbb{R}^2$ it would be clear as we want a sigma algebra on $R\times R$ but $[0,\infty)$ is not a number and I can only guess it at this point.

Any explanation is appreciated!

Comment: "The definition of the product sigma algebra..." Is your $\mathcal{B}$ not signifying the Borel sets here?

Comment: By the way, the topology on $\Bbb{R}^{[0,\infty)}$ is the topology of pointwise convergence (i.e. the product topology). It is not metric, so there are no open balls. Given $r \in [0,\infty)$, you have a map $\pi_r : \Bbb{R}^{[0,\infty)} \to \Bbb{R}$ given by $\pi_r(f) = f(r)$. The basic open sets in $\Bbb{R}^{[0,\infty)}$ are then the sets $\pi_r^{-1}(U)$ where $U \subseteq \Bbb{R}$ is open.

Comment: I think it is therefore the other way around. For the product topology you are looking at $\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ and there pointwise convergence for all projections is equivalent to convergence. If all $X_i=\mathbb{R}$, you have $\prod_{i\in I}\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}^{I}$ because then we are looking at all maps at once for given some $x\in I$ and is hence the product sigma algebra in the general case where we replace $I$ with any interval we would like?

Comment: Well this is where I'm unsure what you're meaning by "the product sigma algebra." The bottom line is that $\bigotimes_{i\in I} \mathcal{B}(X_i) \neq \mathcal{B}\left(\prod_{i\in I} X_i\right)$ for most topological spaces $X_i$ and index sets $I$. The exception is if $I$ is finite and the $X_i$ are separable metric spaces. Hence for example, $\bigotimes_{i=1}^n \mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R}) = \mathcal{B}\left(\Bbb{R}^n \right)$ for all $n$, but not for infinite products.

Answer (score 0):

$\{\times_{x\in [0,\infty)} B_x: \ B_x \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\forall x\in [0,\infty) \ \text{and} \ B_x \neq [0,\infty) \ \text{only for countably many}\ x\in [0,\infty)\}$ is easily seen to be a $\sigma-$ algebra and the product $\sigma-$ algebra is contained in it. [Loosly speaking, any set in the product $\sigma-$ algebra depends on at most countable number of coordinates]. Now $\{f\in \mathbb R^{[0,\infty)}: f(t) >0 \, \text {for some}\,\, t\}$ (being union of $\{f\in \mathbb R^{[0,\infty)}: f(t) >0 \}$ over all $t$) is an open set which does not depend on only countbale number of coordinates and hence does not belong to the product $\sigma-$ algebra.